# Update table and trigger in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

What I want: When every `defaussee` are equal to 1 I want to turn them to 0.
Here is my table

```
create table Pile(
    id_carte Int NOT NULL,
    id_pilecarte Int NOT NULL,
    defaussee Int NOT NULL,
    id_personne Int
);
```

To do that I want to use a trigger on `Pile`.
But I know that I can't modify my table into that trigger.

Here is what I have:

```
create or replace trigger trg_pile_porte_vide
    after update 
    on Pile
    for each row

    declare
        v_count Int;
    begin
        -- pile tresor
        select count(*) into v_count from (select id_carte from Pile where id_pilecarte = 0 and defaussee = 0 and id_personne is null);
        -- toutes les cartes sont defause
        if(v_count = 0) then
            update Pile set defaussee = 0 where id_pilecarte = 0;
        end if;

        -- pile tresor
        select count(*) into v_count from (select id_carte from Pile where id_pilecarte = 1 and defaussee = 0 and id_personne is null);
        -- toutes les cartes sont defause
        if(v_count = 0) then
            update Pile set defaussee = 0 where id_pilecarte = 1;
        end if;
    end;
```

Can't somebody help me ?

The error is not only on the `UPDATE`. Oracle shout from the first `SELECT`. He doesn't want that I Read/Write on `Pile` during a trigger on `Pile`.

Comment: What happens if you change your trigger to a "BEFORE UPDATE" trigger instead of "AFTER"? Oracle prevents you from manipulating data after updating it, since you are basically creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Try use `if(:new.defaussee=1) then :new.defaussee:=0; end if;`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
UPDATE Pile
SET defaussee = 0
WHERE (id_pilecarte, 1) IN (
    SELECT id_pilecarte, MIN(defaussee)
    FROM Pile
    GROUP BY id_pilecarte
    HAVING MIN(defaussee) = 1
);
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a boolean type at SQL level, only in PL/SQL.